# Python: sorting list via parameter in another function

Tags: python, function, sorting, parameters

I'm trying to get the `fruit()` function to sort using `key=sortby()` and then print to screen - either within `fruit()` or within it's own function.

It works fine when there is no `fruit()` function, but I'm having difficulties working out the right syntax to pass `par` as a parameter to be used in `fruit()`

```
fruit = [["Apples", 30], ["Bananas", 100], ["Pears", 0], ["Peaches", 20]]

def sortby(par):
    return par[1]

def fruit():
    rate = []

    fruit.sort(key=sortby, reverse=True)

    for success in fruit:
        rate.append(success[0])
        rate.append(success[1])

    str = str(rate)

print(str)
```

Comment: You function is named `fruit`... so inside the function `fruit` refers to the function itself - not the `fruit` list outside it... You also never return `rate`.... and that last `print(str)` is just going to print the builtin method - unless that's supposed to be indented within `fruit` (or whatever name you choose)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You need to return a value from your `fruit` function
2. You need to give the `fruit` function a different name from the list
3. You need to actually call the `fruit` function at some point
4. Avoid using `str` as a variable name, as this is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) in Python.

The `sortby` function works fine, however.

```
fruit = [["Apples", 30], ["Bananas", 100], ["Pears", 0], ["Peaches", 20]]

def sortby(par):
    return par[1]

def sort_fruit():
    rate = []

    fruit.sort(key=sortby, reverse=True)

    for success in fruit:
        rate.append(success[0])
        rate.append(success[1])

    return rate

print(sort_fruit())
```

Comment: Or the entire program could be: `fuit = [...]`, then `print([el for pair in sorted(fruit, key=lambda L: L[1], reverse=True) for el in pair])`... but that's probably a bit much for now...

Comment: Thank you very much. I just seem to have a mental block when trying to pass variables via parameters in functions. But this works brilliantly - thank you!